# Layout computation duration is too long

Tags: android, layout

I start an Activity which initializes a complex layout. This is a table, with a lot of images, textviews, EditTexts, Checboxes, Spinners and ActionListeners. The position of each item is different, depending on the callee where it is started. So the information is stored in the Intent.

This means: The layout can not be constructed via XML since all the items always have a different position.

The problem: This computation takes a lot of time. It can take up to 400 ms before the activity can start. This is very bad.

How can I avoid this? As far as I know, I can not precompute the layout. It is not possible to clone views. An if I create that view in another Activity and assign it here, I get some crashes as well.

Comment: 400ms means around half a second i think it would be ok

Comment: xml layout's are loads faster then java code views and 400ms is not a very long duration.

Comment: You're going to get better answers with some additional detail as to the structure of your layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your layout in pieces and animate it the entire construction for the user. Might take > 400 ms to complete, but the user is gaga for the experience of watching your beautiful layout get created before his eyes. More advice than this is difficult to give without layout details from you.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that 400 ms is not a lot of time.

One more thing you can try is that you can create your layout in xml files and in your activity create a function which reposition all elements. For repositioning first you can get the layout params of your views then you can set new positions and then you can setlayoutparams on your views again according to new position.

Comment: 400 mx is actually very much when you do a click and expect a respone. Reorganizing the layout is actually what I do now - unfortunaetly this is what takes the most of the time.

Comment: I was experiencing similar issues. I ended redesigning the layout to make it work as a ListView... I do not know if that could be your case.

Comment: I think if you will clone view then also you need to change position of all your views. So that will be the same as i have suggested above that you can reposition all of views.

Comment: @BharatSharma View clones are not allowed in Android

Comment: @Caumons but you can inflate them to make their copies.

Comment: Yes and inflating them is not the solution. The time consuming reoganization has to done after the inflation.

Comment: @BharatSharma Remember that inflating XML is an expensive operation, so inflating the same a lot of times is very time consuming

Comment: @Caumons Creating views at runtime is also time consuming and setting all parameters and layout params on views is also time consuming. As you have told me that cloning is not allowed in view so I was explaining the alternative of cloning so that others can also have little help.

Comment: @BharatSharma Of course, no problem, we are here to help each other! :)